# How to add a header to a Vapor response (Cache-Control)

Tags: vapor

I have a controller using a get handler that returns a `Future<Content>`. I would like to add a header to the response (Cache-Control to be specific). I was thinking that it should be easy but I'm not finding how to do it. Which would be the way to add a header in this case? When we are working with `Content` instead of `Response`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve the problem you could write your endpoint like this

```swift
struct Something: Content {
    let text: String
}
router.get("customresponse") { req -> Future<Response> in
    return try Something(text: "Hello world").encode(for: req).map { response in
        response.http.headers.add(name: .cacheControl, value: "something")
        return response
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mike's answer is spot on... This worked for me.  As a further reference, I used a value to extend the cache for 1 day on all public caches.

```swift
req.headers.add(name: .cacheControl, value: "public, max-age=86400")
```